# Windows 10 recovery drive (usb stick) breaks after first use

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have some problems with my Windows 10 bootsector (I think I wiped it by accident). I created USB stick repair drive and I am able to go to console to try some stuff. However, if I try command bootrec /RebuildBcd and reboot my PC recovery disk itself doesn't work anymore. I'm seeing message "The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors. Error code: 0xc000000f". Is there anything I can do to prevent recreating recovery drive every 10 min ?

Comment: Care to comment ?

Comment: On 0xc000000f error are you booting HDD or USB? Boot Configuration Data (BCD) has nothing to do with boot sectors (which are not used for UEFI boot on newer computers)

Comment: Exactly, it has nothing to do with the usb but it somehow breaks. I'm booting from USB when error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

First and MAIN thing - there are two ways of booting USB on UEFI firmware!

For repairing UEFI boot select "USB..UEFI" boot for booting USB! (ha-ha how many boots in one sentence)

Explicit commands for repairing boot:

```
1. bootsect.exe /nt60 ALL /force /MBR (you don't need this on UEFI)
```

For UEFI:

```
2a. bcdboot.exe N:\windows /s M: /f UEFI
```

Obviously N: drive is where Windows is installed

M: drive is EFI System on HDD

For BIOS:

```
2b. bcdboot N:\Windows /s M: /f BIOS
```

M: is active partition on HDD